# Getting only necessary headers out of boost

Tags: c++, boost

I need to submit an assignment, but I only want to include the header files from boost that I actually used (I made use of boost::shared_ptr and boost::function). I tried doing so manually, but I'm missing some header files and everytime i go to add them, it turns out I'm missing more. Is there a quick easy way to find out exactly what headers I actually need?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `bcp` command is made for this:

> NAME
>
> ```
>    bcp - extract subsets of Boost
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    bcp --list [options] module-list
>    bcp [options] module-list output-path
>    bcp --report [options] module-list html-file
>    bcp --help
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    Copies all the files, including dependencies, found in module-list to
>    output-path. output-path must be an existing path.
> ```

But you will probably be surprised to see just how interdependent these Boost headers are.

Comment: Do I need to build bcp? I can only find source files for it in my boost directory

Comment: Dunno. My Debian/Ubuntu machines have it from the `libboost1.42-dev` package.

Comment: had to do this on windows recently - Go into the tools\bcp folder and type "..\..\bjam.exe --toolset=msvc"

Comment: bcp copies way too much stuff.  You will find it copying html files, tutorials, jpegs, and project files for compilers that were in fashion when some of you were in diapers.

Comment: I was looking if I could extract numeric_cast using this, but either I am doing something wrong or the dependency tree is gigantic. It listed 936 files of which 853 were header files.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [`bcp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html) to do exactly that -- copy out the parts of Boost you need and no more.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually another solution to your issue: the preprocessor.

The compiler you use should have a switch to only run the preprocessor: `-E` on gcc and clang. Given this, you can preprocess the two files you include, and stash the result of this run into a header file (each) of your own.

Add header guards, include the already preprocessed headers in lieu of the regular boost headers, and you're done.

Of course there might be some repetition between the two headers, a diff tool could potentially help you spotting it and factoring it in another common header... but for an assignment I would certainly not bother.

You might also consider telling your teacher that as he does not ask you to provide the standard library headers you compiled with, he should not be asking for the boost headers you used.